# Getting data from view to controller using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I pass the data input by user from view to controller in codeigniter Php using get or post method? I'm currently new to codeigniter..thanks!

AddProduct.php (my view)

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="SaveProductController"></br></br></br>
        <table border='1' align='center'>
            <tr>
                <td>ID: </td><td><input type="text" name="id" 
                                        value="<?php echo $GetProductId->id + 1; ?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td><td><input type="text" name="description"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><input type="submit" name="addProduct" value="Add Product"><td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

SaveProductController .php (my Controller)

```
class SaveProductController extends CI_Controller{

function index($description){
    $this->load->model('ProductDao');
    $data['id'] = $this->id;
    $data['description'] = $this->description;
    print_r($data);
    //$this->ProductDao->saveProduct();
}
```

}

ProductDao.php

```
 function saveProduct() {
    $data = array(
    'id' => $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('id')),
    'description' => $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('description')),
    'price' => $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('price')),
    'size' => $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('size')),
    'aisle' => $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('aisle')),
    );

    $query = $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279282/how-to-process-a-form-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created controller named : Test_controller and view named : manage_test_controller and using below code you can get data from view file to controller.

Test_controller.php

```
 class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {

        var $controller = "user";
        var $formValues = array();
    function manage_user() {               

                $this->formValues['formAction'] = SITEURL . '/' . 
                $this->controller . '/manage_' . $this->controller;

                if (isset($_POST['displayName']))
                    $this->formValues['displayName'] = $_POST['displayName']; 
                else
                    $this->formValues['displayName'] = "";
                if (isset($_POST['userEmail']))
                    $this->formValues['userEmail'] = $_POST['userEmail']; else
                    $this->formValues['userEmail'] = "";                   

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view($this->controller . '/manage_' . 
            $this->controller, $this->formValues);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
```

Manage_test_controller.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart($formAction); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Display Name'); ?><em>*</em></td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('displayName',$displayName); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Email'); ?><em>*</em></td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('userEmail',$userEmail); ?></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Hope this code will help you.... :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->base_url();?>/controllername/methodname"></br></br></br>
        <table border='1' align='center'>
            <tr>
                <td>ID: </td><td><input type="text" name="id" 
                                        value="<?php echo $GetProductId->id + 1; ?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td><td><input type="text" name="description"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><input type="submit" name="addProduct" value="Add Product"><td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

observe the change in action

and in your comtroller specified method get values as shown below

```
$id=$this->input->post('id')
$idescription=$this->input->post('description')
```

then send these to model and do what ever you want

load url helper library to make `$this->baseurl()` to work other wise hard code it using `localhost/path...`

Comment: +1, when your using the `index` function you don't need the method name in the form action, by default, the index method would be launched.

Comment: Also `base_url` is a helper function, no need to use `$this`, check [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) and [form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Comment: @Sivagopal Manpragada hi. thanks for your help. i have successfully display the data in my page. if you don't mind, what does this line means? `action="<?php echo $this->baseurl();?>/controllername/methodname">` ..i have configure baseurl on /application/config/config/baseurl = 'index.php'

Comment: localhost/codeigniter/index.php/ this part is called baseurl() read codeigniter manual of base_url() can you accept my answer